# How do i make a customtkinter button run a function without freezing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, customtkinter

right now am trying to make a customtkinter GUI for my code
the problem that am running in which I cannot really find an answer to it is as follows,
I am trying to make a button run a specific bit of code and I want to be able to do it multiple times, normally that's not a problem but in this case the code takes a bit of time to finish (1hr)

during this 1hr the GUI is not responsive till the code has been executed

so i tried to run it by threading just as follows

```
btn = customtkinter.CTkButton(misc_frame, text="Press",command =threading.Thread(target=main).start)
```

this fixes the problem of the GUI/ application freezing but it produces 2 new problems

1-once I hit the button 1 time I cannot hit it again to run the same bit of code
as it is a thread

2-if I close the GUI am trying to have it so the code just terminates and I have no idea how to implement that

```
btn = customtkinter.CTkButton(misc_frame, text="Press",command =threading.Thread(target=main).start)
```

so i ran this code it solved 1 problem but brought about 2 other problems which are

1- I cannot hit the same button again to run the same function after it finished it the first time

2- if I close the GUI the code keeps on running and I would like that to happen

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import threading
import time




def main(button_loc):
    customtkinter.CTkButton.configure(button_loc,state="disabled",fg_color="red",text= "Running" , font=('Helvetica', 18, 'bold'))
    x = 0
    while x <=10 :
        x += 1
        print("hello")
        time.sleep(1)
    customtkinter.CTkButton.configure(button_loc,state="normal",fg_color="green",text= "START" , font=('Helvetica', 18, 'bold'))
    print("done")

#run app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # System Setting
    customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
    customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")

    # App Frame
    app = customtkinter.CTk()
    app.geometry("1100x580")
    app.title("Program 2.0")

    #frames
    Prices_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(app, width=500, height=260)
    Prices_frame.place(x = 10, y = 10)

    misc_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(app, width=200, height=260) 
    misc_frame.place(x = 520, y= 10)

    #prices frame Labels
    label_Runes = customtkinter.CTkLabel(Prices_frame, text="Runes", width = 10, height = 10, font=('Helvetica', 18, 'bold'))
    label_Runes.place(x = 20, y=10)

    label_Souls = customtkinter.CTkLabel(Prices_frame, text="Souls", width = 10, height = 10, font=('Helvetica', 18, 'bold'))
    label_Souls.place(x = 140, y=10)

    label_Relics = customtkinter.CTkLabel(Prices_frame, text="Relics", width = 10, height = 10, font=('Helvetica', 18, 'bold'))
    label_Relics.place(x = 260, y=10)

    label_Shards = customtkinter.CTkLabel(Prices_frame, text="Shards", width = 10, height = 10, font=('Helvetica', 18, 'bold'))
    label_Shards.place(x = 380, y=10)



    #misc_frame Labels
    tax_rate = customtkinter.CTkLabel(misc_frame, text="TAX Rate:", width = 10, height = 10, font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
    tax_rate.place(x = 10, y = 18 )
    profit_margin = customtkinter.CTkLabel(misc_frame, text="Profit Margin:", width = 10, height = 10, font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
    profit_margin.place(x = 10, y = 57 )



    #prices frame Entries

    entry_t4_runes = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T4 runes",width=100)
    entry_t4_runes.place(x = 20 , y = 55)

    entry_t4_souls = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T4 souls",width=100)
    entry_t4_souls.place(x = 140 , y = 55)

    entry_t4_relics = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T4 relics",width=100)
    entry_t4_relics.place(x = 260 , y = 55)

    entry_t4_shards = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T4 shards",width=100)
    entry_t4_shards.place(x = 380 , y = 55)



    entry_t5_runes = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T5 runes",width=100)
    entry_t5_runes.place(x = 20 , y = 95)

    entry_t5_souls = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T5 souls",width=100)
    entry_t5_souls.place(x = 140 , y = 95)

    entry_t5_relics = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T5 relics",width=100)
    entry_t5_relics.place(x = 260 , y = 95)

    entry_t5_shards = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T5 shards",width=100)
    entry_t5_shards.place(x = 380 , y = 95)



    entry_t6_runes = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T6 runes",width=100)
    entry_t6_runes.place(x = 20 , y = 135)

    entry_t6_souls = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T6 souls",width=100)
    entry_t6_souls.place(x = 140 , y = 135)

    entry_t6_relics = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T6 relics",width=100)
    entry_t6_relics.place(x = 260 , y = 135)

    entry_t6_shards = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T6 shards",width=100)
    entry_t6_shards.place(x = 380 , y = 135)



    entry_t7_runes = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T7 runes",width=100)
    entry_t7_runes.place(x = 20 , y = 175)

    entry_t7_souls = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T7 souls",width=100)
    entry_t7_souls.place(x = 140 , y = 175)

    entry_t7_relics = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T7 relics",width=100)
    entry_t7_relics.place(x = 260 , y = 175)

    entry_t7_shards = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T7 shards",width=100)
    entry_t7_shards.place(x = 380 , y = 175)



    entry_t8_runes = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T8 runes",width=100)
    entry_t8_runes.place(x = 20 , y = 215)

    entry_t8_souls = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T8 souls",width=100)
    entry_t8_souls.place(x = 140 , y = 215)

    entry_t8_relics = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T8 relics",width=100)
    entry_t8_relics.place(x = 260 , y = 215)

    entry_t8_shards = customtkinter.CTkEntry(Prices_frame, placeholder_text="T8 shards",width=100)
    entry_t8_shards.place(x = 380 , y = 215)

    entry_tax_rate = customtkinter.CTkEntry(misc_frame, placeholder_text="Tax rate (%)",width=125)
    entry_tax_rate.place(x = 70, y = 10 )
    entry_profit_margin = customtkinter.CTkEntry(misc_frame, placeholder_text="Profit Margin(%)",width=104)
    entry_profit_margin.place(x = 90, y = 50)

    btn = customtkinter.CTkButton(misc_frame, text="START",command=lambda: mp.Process(target=main,args=(btn,)).start(),fg_color="green",font=('Helvetica', 18, 'bold'))
    btn.place(x = 30 , y = 90)


    app.mainloop()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\code\program 2.0\venv002\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\code\program 2.0\test.py", line 138, in <lambda>
    btn = customtkinter.CTkButton(misc_frame, text="START",command=lambda: mp.Process(target=main,args=(btn,)).start(),fg_color="green",font=('Helvetica', 18, 'bold'))
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 94, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_tkinter.tkapp' object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 132, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: For the first item, you need to create new instance of `threading.Thread()` when the button is clicked: `command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=main).start()`.  It is not clear what you want for the second item.

Comment: thanks so much for Your help man, is there a way i can do that as well with multi proccessing as my code doesnot have alot of down time and it does alot of calculations

Comment: You can use `multiprocessing.Process()` instead.

Comment: it works if i donot pass an arg to it `    btn = customtkinter.CTkButton(misc_frame, text="START",command=lambda: mp.Process(target=main,args=(btn,)).start(),fg_color="green",font=('Helvetica', 18, 'bold'))`

Comment: and in the `main()` function i am trying to have it so when it starts running it , it disables the button to prevent the user from starting another proccesses while this one is running

Comment: i tried doing so by passing the args `btn` to the main function `def main(button_loc):
    customtkinter.CTkButton.configure(button_loc,state="disabled",fg_color="red",text= "Running" , font=('Helvetica', 18, 'bold'))`

Comment: but it shows me Ran out of input error

Comment: am bad at explanation so i put in the the bit of code above

Comment: Cannot share widgets across processes.

Comment: what do i do if i want to disable the button when the proccess is running and enable it when it is finished enable it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tkinter` widgets cannot be shared across processes, so you need to disable and enable the button in current process.  You can use `.after()` to check periodically whether the child process has finished or not.

Below is an example:

```py
# function to be executed in child process
def main():
    import time

    for i in range(10):
        print("hello")
        time.sleep(1)

    print("done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import customtkinter as ctk
    import multiprocessing as mp

    def start(btn):
        # disable the button
        btn.configure(state="disabled", fg_color="red", text="Running")

        # start the child process
        p = mp.Process(target=main)
        p.start()

        # function to check whether child process has terminated or not
        def wait_for_process():
            if p.is_alive():
                # child process is still running, schedule next checking
                btn.after(100, wait_for_process)
            else:
                # child process has terminated, enable the button
                btn.configure(state="normal", text="START", fg_color="green")

        # start the periodic checking
        wait_for_process()

    root = ctk.CTk()
    btn = ctk.CTkButton(root, text="START", fg_color="green",
                        font=("Helvetica", 18, "bold"),
                        command=lambda: start(btn))
    btn.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i love from the bottom of my heart, you have no idea how close i was to punshing my screen XD